# Explaining derivative being used to derive tensor properties

Tags: partial-derivative, coordinate-systems, tensors, chain-rule

I'm doing some self-study on tensor calculus for physics, and I've come across a derivative that I can't quite wrap my head around. It looks like this:

$\frac{d}{dt}(\frac{\partial x'^i}{\partial x^j})=\frac{\partial^2 x'^i}{\partial x^j\partial x^k}\frac{dx^k}{dt}$

where summation over repeated indices is implied. This came up when investigating a change of coordinates from the unprimed to the primed frame.

Right now, I'm trying to interpret it as this $\frac{\partial x'^i}{\partial x^j}$ being some variable, say $w$, that depends on each $x^k$ and thus we need the chain rule:

$\frac{dw}{dt}=\frac{\partial w}{\partial x^k}\frac{dx^k}{dt}$

But, then I start to get hung up on the notation — is it legal to assert

$\frac{\partial w}{\partial x^k}=\frac{\partial (\frac{\partial x'^i}{\partial x^j})}{\partial x^k}=\frac{\partial^2 x'^i}{\partial x^j\partial x^k}$?

I am wary of manipulating derivatives exactly as I manipulate fractions, because I fear I am sweeping subtle things under the rug.

Can someone verify whether my interpretation here is correct, or offer some other insight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your interpretation is correct. You could also see this as an operator equality:
$$\frac{d}{dt} = \frac{\partial x^k}{\partial t}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^k}$$
(which is just another statement of the chain rule) and then use this to replace the $\frac{d}{dt}$ in your equation.

Comment: I like this, thanks!